# ¿Cuál es la función del pronombre interrogativo "cómo" en una oración interrogativa indirecta?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis, categorías-gramaticales

Maestros y maestras,

Me fascina el analisis sintáctico. Hoy me topé con esta oración:

> Carmen le preguntaba **cómo** iba el divorcio.

"Cómo" es, obviamente, **un pronombre interrogativo** (se llama también "adverbio interrogativo", no sé qué recomienda la RAE) pero me pregunto qué función de dependencia tiene.

Mi mejor suposición es que su función sintáctica es **complemento circunstancial de modo**, pero, si así fuera, la frase no tendría sentido. Por consiguiente, omitiendo el "cómo", se convertirá en "Carmen le preguntaba iba el divorcio". Y, según lo que sé, un "complemento circunstancial" tiene un papel opcional y lo podemos suprimir sin que la frase cambie de sentido.

Respetuosamente, Marcello.

PS: Me alegraría si alguien, en su respuesta, pudiera incluir un enlace de la RAE.

Comment: cómo no es un pronombre. https://dle.rae.es/cómo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El adverbio interrogativo "cómo" (al igual que los adverbios interrogativos "dónde" y "cuándo") tiene una doble función:

- introducir una pregunta indirecta (subordinada)
- desempeñarse como complemento circunstancial dentro de la pregunta indirecta (subordinada)

No es verdad que los complementos circunstanciales sean siempre prescindibles -- a veces agregan información necesaria para la comunicación:

A: ¿Cómo va el divorcio?

B no puede responder: "Va." Puede responder: "Va bien."

Además, en la pregunta indirecta la palabra interrogativa es necesaria como nexo, para vincular la proposición subordinada con la principal.

Nota: Reservamos la denominación "pronombre interrogativo" para aquellas palabras interrogativas que se desempeñan como pronombres (en función de sujeto u objeto), como *qué, cuál/es, quién/es*. "qué" y "cuál/es" también pueden ser determinantes interrogativos cuando están acompañados por sustantivos.

Comment: Es impresionante la respuesta, me inclino. 
No entendí solo una cosa ; que es la diferencia exacta entre la función de "introducir una pregunta indirecta (subordinada), y de ser un "nexo para vincular la proposición subordinada con la principal" ? A mí esas dos funciones me parecen tener el mismo papel. (O sea, podríamos considerar el "nexo" como siendo una tercera función o solo lo añadió para reinforzar el punto 1) "introducir una pregunta indirecta" ?

Comment: Usé ambas expresiones como sinónimas: "cómo" es un nexo que introduce la pregunta indirecta.